# Chef Recipe to do a SVN Checkout

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to run a chef recipe that will install SVN on an Ubuntu client and then checkout a SVN subversion repository to the client machine. The following is the code:

```
#Installing svn
package "subversion" do
action :install
end

#Checkout SVN repo
bash "Checking out Antitheft Repository" do
cwd "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}"
code <<-EOH
svn co --username 'userxxx' --password 'passxxx' 'http://example.com/svn/trunk/yyy'
EOH
end
```

The command

```
svn co --username 'userxxx' --password 'passxxx' 'http://example.com/svn/trunk/yyy'
```

works perfectly well when run on a terminal on the client, but when the same command is executed through the recipe no errors are displayed nor is the checkout done.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you set the log level to debug (via the client.rb file) and paste the output from the console?

Comment: I am pretty new to chef, can you please tell me where this file resides. as "locate client.rb" lists multiple instances for it

Comment: It should be in /etc/chef/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the built-in [scm](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_scm.html) resource:

```
package "subversion"

subversion "Antitheft" do
  repository "http://example.com/svn/trunk/yyy"
  destination "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/antitheft"
  svn_username "userxxx"
  svn_password "passxxx"
end
```

Comment: And you could improve this further by using an encrypted data bad to hold the subversion credentials.

Comment: What if it is in a local file?

Comment: What in a local file? Then use just some Ruby code to read the contents of that file.